# Access DOM element in onload function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, calculator, onload

Hey i want to build this calculator that upon page load is supposed to generate random numbers and depict them in the DOM. Now I get this error message saying: "cannot assign to function call". 
Can someone help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

```js
let add1;
let add2;

function displayNewEquation() {
  add1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  add2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  document.getElementsByTagName("equation") = `<p> ${add1} + ${add2} = </p>`;
}

window.onload = () => {
  displayNewEquation();
};

function checkEquation() {
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("solution").value);
  console.log(input);
  if (input == add1 + add2) {
    displayNewEquation();
  } else {
    var inputfield = document.getElementById("solution");
    inputfield.style.borderColor = "crimson";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>mathle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Addition.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Logic/Addition.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="additionIntro">
      <p class="title">
        - Addition -
      </p>
      <button class="back" onclick="goHome()">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="additionMain">
      <div class="calculation">
        <p class="equation">9 + 13 =</p>
        <input id="solution" type="number" oninput="checkEquation()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("equation") = ` this is invalid as the error says, you cant assign a value to some function call. You probably meant to set the `innerHTML` property of the returned DOM object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors is in this line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("equation") = `<p> ${add1} + ${add2} = </p>`;
```

1. `.getElementsByTagName`:

   `equation` is a class, not a tag name, use `.getElementsByClassName('equation')[0]` or `.querySelector('.equation')` instead.
2. Assignment to function call

   You can assign values only to variables and object properties, but not to function call results. That wouldn't even be meaningful, (as JS doesn't have pointers): You would try to override the return value of the function, without even knowing what it is.

   In your case, you're trying to override the contents of the returned DOM element. That can be done by assigning to a property or calling a function.

- `.innerHTML`:

  ```js
  let add1;
  let add2;

  function displayNewEquation() {
    add1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    add2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    document.querySelector(".equation").innerHTML = `<p> ${add1} + ${add2} = </p>`;
  }

  window.onload = () => {
    displayNewEquation();
  };

  function checkEquation() {
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("solution").value);
    console.log(input);
    if (input == add1 + add2) {
      displayNewEquation();
    } else {
      var inputfield = document.getElementById("solution");
      inputfield.style.borderColor = "crimson";
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>mathle</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Addition.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./Logic/Addition.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="additionIntro">
        <p class="title">
          - Addition -
        </p>
        <button class="back" onclick="goHome()">Back</button>
      </div>
      <div class="additionMain">
        <div class="calculation">
          <p class="equation">9 + 13 =</p>
          <input id="solution" type="number" oninput="checkEquation()" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- `.textContent`:

  ```js
  let add1;
  let add2;

  function displayNewEquation() {
    add1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    add2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    document.querySelector(".equation").textContent = `${add1} + ${add2} =`;
  }

  window.onload = () => {
    displayNewEquation();
  };

  function checkEquation() {
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("solution").value);
    console.log(input);
    if (input == add1 + add2) {
      displayNewEquation();
    } else {
      var inputfield = document.getElementById("solution");
      inputfield.style.borderColor = "crimson";
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>mathle</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Addition.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./Logic/Addition.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="additionIntro">
        <p class="title">
          - Addition -
        </p>
        <button class="back" onclick="goHome()">Back</button>
      </div>
      <div class="additionMain">
        <div class="calculation">
          <p class="equation">9 + 13 =</p>
          <input id="solution" type="number" oninput="checkEquation()" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As @Patrick Evans commented, it looks like your setting the Html for the equation element was not using the innerHTML value. I'm not sure what else you are looking for from your example but the snippet below at least runs. Maybe you can update your question if this is not the issue:

```js
let add1;
let add2;

function displayNewEquation() {
  add1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  add2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  // This was the only line change
  document.getElementsByTagName("equation").innerHTML = '<p> ${add1} + ${add2} = </p>';
}

window.onload = () => {
  displayNewEquation();
};

function checkEquation() {
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("solution").value);
  console.log(input);
  if (input == add1 + add2) {
    displayNewEquation();
  } else {
    var inputfield = document.getElementById("solution");
    inputfield.style.borderColor = "crimson";
  }
}

function goHome(){
  alert("Do something");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>mathle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Addition.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Logic/Addition.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="additionIntro">
      <p class="title">
        - Addition -
      </p>
      <button class="back" onclick="goHome()">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="additionMain">
      <div class="calculation">
        <p class="equation">9 + 13 =</p>
        <input id="solution" type="number" oninput="checkEquation()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As @FZs pointed out, I forgot that had "equations" as the class, and I sure did forget the innerHTML at the end thanks!